# Webhook url is not working

Tags: webhooks, uber-api

We are integrating the UBER RIDE Api in our application, when we request for ride and for getting ride state change status by using WEBHOOK URL. So as per UBER Doc. we integrate the API as per document suggest and also put the WEBHOOK URL on the dashboard of UBER.

Webhook url is not hitting at all and no getting any events on it.
Please suggest us what is problem we are doing.

My Webhook URL : http://ec2-52-1-133-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com/PROJECTS/FairFare/trunk/services/send_push_on_uber.php

Answer (score 1):

We are not seeing issues with webhooks currently. Here is our webhooks [guide](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/webhooks). So it is probably setup on your side. Here is the checklist

- Verify again that your redirect URL is setup on the Application Dashboard.
- In order to make sure that your webhook URL is working as expected - please use a site like http://testwebhooks.com/ and set up new webhook URL
- Make sure you have all required scopes selected
- Check [webhook](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/webhooks) documentation for more info

Comment: We create the new URL link https://stag.mobiloitte.com/PROJECTS/FairFare/trunk/services/send_push_on_uber.php as per guidance. now we are not getting any response from your side and when we hit manually with curl, it working fine for us. Could you please suggest us, where is the problem to hitting the webhook url. Example : curl -d '{"data": "hi"}' https://stag.mobiloitte.com/PROJECTS/FairFare/trunk/services/send_push_on_uber.php

Comment: Webhook url response get delay or also sometime response object not getting from your side. Webhook url : https://stag.mobiloitte.com/PROJECTS/FairFare/trunk/services/send_push_on_uber.php. please suggest us what going on this link.